# $.each function to get all spans data

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all data-name atributes from this html section

```
<div class='get-all'>
    <div class='left-wrapper'>
        <div class='field-wrapper'>
            <div class='field'> <span class='product-id' data-name='itemId'>5</span>

                <img src='carousel/images/120231671_1GG.jpg' width='52' height='52'> <span class='final-descript' data-name='itemDescription'>Product 1</span>
 <span class='product-id' data-name='itemAmount'>225,99</span>
 <span class='product-id' data-name='itemQuantity'>1</span> 
            </div>
            <div class='fix'></div>
            <div class='field'> <span class='review-price'>$ &nbsp;225,99</span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='field-wrapper'>
            <div class='field'> <span class='product-id' data-name='itemId'>4</span>

                <img src='carousel/images/120231671_1GG.jpg' width='52' height='52'> <span class='final-descript' data-name='itemDescription'>Product 2</span>
 <span class='product-id' data-name='itemAmount'>699,80</span>
 <span class='product-id' data-name='itemQuantity'>1</span> 
            </div>
            <div class='fix'></div>
            <div class='field'> <span class='review-price'>$ &nbsp;699,80</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='left-wrapper'> <span class='f-itens'>Total</span><span id='fff' class='f-value'>925,79</span>

        <hr class='f-hr' /> <span class='f-itens'>Shipping</span><span class='f-value' id='f-value'> - </span>

        <hr class='f-hr' />
        <div class='f-itens tots'>Total Price</div><span class='f-value' id='pagar'>-</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this javascript

```
$(".get-all").each(function(index, element){
        $('[data-name]').each(function(index, element) {
            if($(this).attr("data-name")) {
                if (startsWith($(this).attr("data-name"),"itemAmount")) {
                    var a = $(this).html()
                    var b = a.replace(".", "");
                    var c = b.replace(",", ".");

                    params[$(this).attr("data-name") + (index+1)] = c;


                } else {
                    params[$(this).attr("data-name") + (index+1)] = $(this).html();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

But I'm only get the first data-name span atributes, like this

```
ItemId = 5
ItemDescription = Product 1
ItemAmount 225,99
ItemQuantity = 1
```

How To get all attribute-name inside this spans? Thanks for all replyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple

```
$('[data-name]').each(function(index, elem) {
    // do things with index and elem
    $(elem); // Will be your span 
});
```

will get you all elements with a `data-name` attribute.

Comment: What does running a `$('[data-name]').length` in the console of your browser's dev tools tell you?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the data present in all data-name and submit them as parameters. Unfortunately the way told me, no field is being obtained.

Comment: Submit it how and where? `$('[data-name]')` will get you a collection of all elements that have a data-name attribute. `$('[data-name]').length` will get you the number of elements in the collection. If you somehow get "All Empty fields" there's a lot more going on and we'll need more code to be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you patient. Give me a time to explain.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I was at work. Please look at my new question, a little more detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495858/jquery-html-css-geting-all-spans-data-name-atributes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.map` and `$.get` and you can directly capture only spans which have `data-name` thus avoiding an additional `if` condition.

```
params = $(element).find("span[data-name]").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("name");
}).get();
```

Based on your comment, I suppose you're wanting, (but don't know why)

```
params = $(element).find("span[data-name]").map(function() {
    var rtn = $(this).data("name");
    return rtn.replace((rtn == 'itemAmount') ? "." : ","), "");
}).get();
```

Comment: How to implement this code? I'm too need verify if data-name is = itemamout, if true, then replace ('.' '') and replace(',' '.'). Please see my update.

Comment: How could it work?Can you help me a little more? I'm not understand how to use this code.

Comment: @EduardoVSales check my edit. If you didn't understand ask a new question, clearly.

Comment: Ok thanks for you reply, but the line 'return rtn.replace((rtn == itemamount) ? "." : ","), "");' have a error and i can not find it to fix.

Comment: And to answer your question I need the iteamout parameter is checked as it receives a value 12.345,00 and need to pass it as follows 12345.00  =)

Comment: Error in same line. Sorry.