# Jquery HTML/CSS Geting all spans data-name atributes

Tags: jquery, html

This question has to do with this other  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482207/each-function-to-get-all-spans-data).
I found part of the problem and would like someone to help me to solve it altogether.

I discovered that in fact my old script works and i only need to  adapt it correctly. See the following situation

**Using this javascript**

```
var addCartData = function(params) {

    $("#content-wrapper .get-all div ").each(function(index, element){
        $(element).find("span").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("data-name")) {
                if (startsWith($(this).attr("data-name"),"itemAmount")) {
                    //rtn.replace((rtn == 'itemAmount') ? "." : ","), "");
                    params[$(this).attr("data-name") + (index+1)] = $(this).html().replace(($(this).html() ?',':","),".");
                    alert($(this).html().replace(($(this).html() ?',':","),"."));
                } else {
                    params[$(this).attr("data-name") + (index+1)] = $(this).html();
                }
            }
        });
    });

};
```

I'm getting all data-names [itemId, itemDescription, itemAmount, itemQuantity] inside spans elements, then the script is working perfectly. But, because design issues, i need to make the script [or similar] works with the same way **[getting all span data-name]** for the following html code:

```
    <div class='get-all'>
<div class='left-wrapper'>


 <div class='field-wrapper'>
<div class='field'>

<span class='product-id' data-name='itemId'>5</span>
<img src='carousel/images/120231671_1GG.jpg' width='52' height='52'>
<span class='final-descript' data-name='itemDescription'>Panfleto 80x40 500un</span>
<span class='product-id' data-name='itemAmount'>225,99</span>

<span class='product-id' data-name='itemQuantity'>1</span> 
</div>
<div class='fix'></div>
<div class='field'>

  <span class='review-price'>R$ &nbsp;225,99</span>
</div>
</div>

 <div class='field-wrapper'>
<div class='field'>

<span class='product-id' data-name='itemId'>4</span>
<img src='carousel/images/120231671_1GG.jpg' width='52' height='52'>
<span class='final-descript' data-name='itemDescription'>Samsung-G-Duos</span>
<span class='product-id' data-name='itemAmount'>699,80</span>

<span class='product-id' data-name='itemQuantity'>1</span> 
</div>
<div class='fix'></div>
<div class='field'>

  <span class='review-price'>R$ &nbsp;699,80</span>
</div>
</div></div>


<div class='left-wrapper'>

<span class='f-itens'>Valor total dos itens</span><span id='fff' class='f-value'>925,79</span>
<hr class='f-hr' />
<span class='f-itens'>Frete</span><span class='f-value' id='f-value'> - </span>
<hr class='f-hr' />
<div class='f-itens tots'>Total a pagar</div><span class='f-value' id='pagar' >-</span>


</div>
</div>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

The problem is that using **the same script for this new html** I get the items several times, tripled, for example, rather than get the value $ 225.99 once, **I receive 3 times**. So does the other fields. How can I adapt the script so you can get the date-names only once as when used with the old html code??

Comment: can you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: just empty the array befopre you loop over all the elements. `params.length = 0` so you don't duplicate data already instered into array

Comment: You may want to resolve your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482207/each-function-to-get-all-spans-data) and accept an answer or update the question to indicate the additional info.

Comment: This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbj7d2w4/4/). But when the user clicks the button instance should be shown 41.45 and 10.15. But what I really need is to get this script to work in the html code that I put above.

Comment: I believe that the error is in the amount of divs that I am using to get to the elements 'span'. Because when i use a smaller amount of divs [As shown in the above fiddle] the script works correctly. Somehow, with more divs the script should be going around.

Comment: Please, see the following image to better understand the situation [link](http://s12.postimg.org/wt32704ot/1_code_block.jpg)

Comment: The problem is that you are using a whole bunch of nested DIV's that you are trying to loop through. Because find() travels through all levels of nested elements (as opposed to just direct children), you are looping through some span's multiple times. Try getting the span's that are under just .get-all instead.

Comment: Ok @akanevsky, but, how to fix the javascript to new html?

Comment: @EduardoVSales I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say "new html" and "old html", but maybe this will work due to being more specific: if you replace $("#content-wrapper .get-all div ").each( with $("#content-wrapper .get-all").find("div.field").each( . This should target the container for each set of fields so that the inner part goes through each field only once.

Comment: @akanevsky Firstly thank you for taking the time to help me. Secondly apologize for failing to be as specific as I would like to be, but this is because I do not speak your language. When I referred to old html mean the html that is on the left side of the image that is on this [link](http://s12.postimg.org/wt32704ot/1_code_block.jpg), the new html is on the right. Anyway your code did not work for me, but gave me a new horizon to look and it is working as follows `$("#content-wrapper .get-all").find("div.field-wrapper").each(`. Thanks very much. Please move it to a answer.

Comment: You're welcome. And your language is fine. I guess I should have looked at the link first, because it does clarify everything. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by @V.Salles, I'm re-posting my comment as an answer, since it led to the solution.

> I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say "new html" and
>   "old html", but maybe this will work due to being more specific: if
>   you replace $("#content-wrapper .get-all div ").each( with
>   $("#content-wrapper .get-all").find("div.field").each( . This should
>   target the container for each set of fields so that the inner part
>   goes through each field only once.

As per @V.Salles, the following adjustment to my suggestion has solved the problem:

```
$("#content-wrapper .get-all").find("div.field-wrapper").each(
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not enough since you have many DIV tags

Try to change this specific line in your javascript code: 
This

```
$("#content-wrapper .get-all div ").each(function(index, element){
```

to

```
$("#content-wrapper .get-all .field-wrapper ").children("field").each(function(index, element){
```

When you only put DIV tag in your javascript (notice you have 3 DIV tags) your code travel to search all SPAN tags that they are belong (children) to then.

Comment: Good. Check if this solution was helpful.